# How to print variables without spaces between values

Tags: python, whitespace, python-2.x

I would like to know how to remove additional spaces when I print something.

Like when I do:

```
print 'Value is "', value, '"'
```

The output will be:

```
Value is " 42 "
```

But I want:

```
Value is "42"
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Don't use `print ...,` (with a trailing comma) if you don't want spaces. Use string concatenation or formatting.

Concatenation:

```
print 'Value is "' + str(value) + '"'
```

Formatting:

```
print 'Value is "{}"'.format(value)
```

The latter is far more flexible, see the [`str.format()` method documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and the [*Formatting String Syntax* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

You'll also come across the older [`%` formatting style](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
print 'Value is "%d"' % value
print 'Value is "%d", but math.pi is %.2f' % (value, math.pi)
```

but this isn't as flexible as the newer `str.format()` method.

In Python 3.6 and newer, you'd use a formatted string (*f-string*):

```
print(f"Value is {value}")
```

Comment: Oh okay I didn't know that, just learning Python, thanks for the quick answer !

Comment: `''.format` style is preferable because it avoids several `%`-style related edge cases such as implicit promotion to `unicode` and unintentional `% tuple`, `% dict` usage.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: not to mention that `str.format()` supports custom formatting for classes; you cannot easily format `datetime` objects with `%` the way you can with `str.format()`, for example. Then there is the recursive field definitions (you can use fields to determine how other fields are formatted), etc.

Answer (score 54):

Just an easy answer for the future which I found easy to use as a starter:
Similar to using `end=''` to avoid a new line, you can use `sep=''` to avoid the white spaces...for this question here, it would look like this:
        `print('Value is "', value, '"', sep = '')`

May it help someone in the future.

Comment: Thank you! this has helped me with an issue that's been bugging me for ages

Comment: This is python 3 specific syntax.

Comment: Super useful tip

Comment: Found very useful when trying to use ternary conditional operators in a print statement, thanks

Answer (score 16):

It's the comma which is providing that extra white space.

One way is to use the string `%` method:

```
print 'Value is "%d"' % (value)
```

which is like `printf` in C, allowing you to incorporate and format the items after `%` by using format specifiers in the string itself. Another example, showing the use of multiple values:

```
print '%s is %3d.%d' % ('pi', 3, 14159)
```

For what it's worth, Python 3 greatly improves the situation by allowing you to specify the separator and terminator for a single `print` call:

```
>>> print(1,2,3,4,5)
1 2 3 4 5

>>> print(1,2,3,4,5,end='<<\n')
1 2 3 4 5<<

>>> print(1,2,3,4,5,sep=':',end='<<\n')
1:2:3:4:5<<
```

Comment: the `%` interpolation is prone to errors with `tuple`s and other peculiar behaviour.

Comment: And yet, somehow, I managed to cobble together the code and have it work first time. Yes, you have to know about the shortcomings of the tools you use. That's true in _any_ field. I'm not the type of developer that tends to pass arbitrary types to my formatting operations :-)

Comment: that is why the `.format` that works without any edge cases on 99.999 % of Python installations a new user can come across, is the more newbie friendly soution-

Comment: @Antti. Err, just out interest, what's the _other_ 0.001%? Or was that just reticence to claim certainty? Not that I have an issue with that, I've done it before myself.

Comment: It means, someone might be learning Python to maintain a solution that runs and is stuck to <= 2.5, or maybe Jython 2.5.

Comment: This works perfectly: print(1,2,3,4,5,sep=':',end='<<\n')

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

Note: This function is not normally available as a built-in since the name print is recognized as the print statement. To disable the statement and use the print() function, use this future statement at the top of your module:

from **future** import print_function

Answer (score 2):

To build off what Martjin was saying.
I'd use string interpolation/formatting.

In Python 2.x which seems to be what you're using due to the lack of parenthesis around the print function you do:

```
print 'Value is "%d"' % value
```

In Python 3.x you'd use the format method instead, so you're code would look like this.

```
message = 'Value is "{}"'
print(message.format(value))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> value=42

>>> print "Value is %s"%('"'+str(value)+'"') 

Value is "42"
```

Comment: No need to have the extra concatenation just to get the `"` characters

Comment: User `repr` or, in this case `%r`