# Trying to break up the users string into my function for a decimal return - Python

Tags: python, string, list, binary

So I am trying to chop the user input of 1s and 0s to print out their decimal counterpart, but no matter what when I enter: "10000000111111110000001100001111" I get 256 for the second set of 8 numbers instead of 255. I am stumped. I get 128 for value 1, but 256 for value 2. I don't think I understand what (number[6:10]) is even doing.

```
def convert(bits):
    answer = 0
    keeper = 128
    for i in bits:
        if(i == '1'):
            answer = answer + keeper
            keeper / 2
    return answer





number = str(input("Please enter a 32-bit integer: "))


value1 = convert(number[0:7])
value2 = convert(number[6:10])

print(value1, value2)
```

Comment: change `keeper / 2` to `keeper /= 2`

Comment: Thank you! It now prints "255.0", how can I get rid of the ".0"?

Comment: `keeper //= 2` will do the trick

Comment: Thank you again! So with this method, If i Continue with a value3 and try and grab the next 8 pieces of string it gives a wrong number no matter what. value1 = convert(number[0:7])
value2 = convert(number[8:16])
value3 = convert(number[16:24]) Value 3 should only be 3, not 192 like it comes out:/ any idea what is going on with this thing? I am just trying to take the 32 bit value and give back  128.255.3.15.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `keeper` isn't being updated when you do `keeper / 2`.

You have to catch the value of that statement and assign it to keeper:

`keeper = keeper // 2` or `keeper //= 2`

Since you want to split the user's input into 8 bit blocks, you should also change the indexes in your slicing. In your case you would want:

```
value1 = convert(number[0:8])
value2 = convert(number[8:16])
```

> I don't think I understand what (number[6:10]) is even doing.

`number` is being set to a string of the number the user inputs, in your case `"10000000111111110000001100001111"`.

By saying `number[6:10]`, you're slicing the string meaning you're getting a specific *piece of the string*. The first number `6` is the starting point and `10` is the endpoint -- but note that `10` is **exclusive** meaning you will get the string starting at index `6` and ending at **but not including** the character at index `10`. Also note that the very first index of the string is `0`, and not `1`. There are some helpful examples [here](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings#string-slices).

Comment: You're trying to convert 8 digit blocks from binary into decimal. 

So you should only be adding `128` to `answer` if the **first** digit in the block is a 1, otherwise you need to update the value of `keeper`. I think [this picture](https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/e/e2/Convert-from-Binary-to-Decimal-Step-3-Version-2.jpg/aid5975-v4-728px-Convert-from-Binary-to-Decimal-Step-3-Version-2.jpg) would be helpful.

As you are traversing your string, you need to be updating the value of `keeper` even when the digit is not 1.

So you should move `keeper //= 2` outside the if (reduce indent).

Comment: Thank you so much! My last issue was "Keeper" not halving when encountering 0s as it should have! Finally figured it out! Thank you again!

Comment: Could I bother you for one last thing? When I run: print(value1,".",value2,".",value3,".",value4) It prints out: 128 . 255 . 3 . 15, how do i get rid of all those spaces?

Comment: You have to use string concatenation or formatting if you don't want spaces between things. You can't use print(`foo` , `bar` , `baz`) as the commas are what gives you the spaces. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669459/how-to-print-variables-without-spaces-between-values)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!