# How do I I get rid of the whitespaces before and after sys.argv when printing?

Tags: python

Here is the code in my test.py file.

```
print ('The 2nd arg is: \'', sys.argv[1], '\'.')
```

Each time I run this command

```
python test.py hello
```

I get this

```
The 2nd arg is: ' hello '.
```

There are whitespaces before and after the string. How do I get rid of them?

I've tried `strip()` which doesn't work.

Comment: The comma in a print statement adds spaces. Use the "+" operator to concatenate without spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print variables without spaces between values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669459/how-to-print-variables-without-spaces-between-values)

Comment: @SurajKothari ...or just set `sep=''`...

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print): *"`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)` - Print `objects` to the text stream `file`, __separated by `sep`__ and followed by `end`"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in your print function. You are getting extra white-spaces because of the `,` inside your print. This should fix the issue:

```
print ('The 2nd arg is: \'' + sys.argv[1] + '\'.')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following formatting:

```
print ("The 2nd arg is:'{}'.".format(sys.argv[1]))
```